# Android: исполнение тяжёлего кода в AsyncTask

Tags: android, java

Всем привет!

Есть "тяжёлые код" - заполнение текстом n-ного количества TextViews. Нужно оптимизировать код, чтобы он работал стабильнее. Появилась идея сделать это с помощью AsyncTask, но вопрос как: нестабильиный код - это заполнение самих текстовых полей,а в **doInBackdround**  использовать UI нельзя.

Не могли бы вы мне почмочь? Большое спасибо!

```
 String file = Utils.openFile(nameOfFile, this);
        myList = file.split(Utils.separator2);

for(i = 0; i < myList.length - 1; i++)
        {
            View view_item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shop_list_item,listView_layout,false);
            final TextView fileText = (TextView)view_item.findViewById(R.id.editText_texter);
            fileText.setText(" " + myList[i].replace("-","\n"));

            if(fileText.getText().toString().contains(bird)) // если есть птичка, то зачёркиваем текст
            {
                strikeText(true,fileText);
            }else{
                strikeText(false,fileText);
            }
    ...
```

Приветствуются любые способы)

Comment: а сколько же этих полей у Вас, что оно там тормозит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё это запихнуть в Runnable. И в цикле вашем отправлять сообщение Handler'у какому-нибудь в UI потоке, который будет писать текст в TextView.

Answer (score 2):

Если хочешь делать это именно с помощью ASyncTask, то обрати внимание на функцию

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(progress);
```

Она вызывается в UI потоке столько раз, сколько вызовешь функцию

```
publishProgress(someProgress);
```

в методе doInBackground().

Answer (score 1):

Не будет работать через `Asynctask` и вот по каким причинам:

1. Модифицировать виджет можно только в том потоке, в котором он был создан
2. `Asynctask` в последних версиях Android'а умеет раскладывать свою задачу на несколько потоков

Так что если в ранних версиях еще и может прокатить, то в новых вряд ли. И вообще создание юай элементов в другом потоке это не очень правильная идея. Надо просто разделить создание виджета (дешевая операция) и его наполнение (может быть длительной операцией)

В качестве альтернативы можно предложить 2 способа:

1. Работа через [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) способ обмена сообщениями между потоками. То есть создаем виджеты в юай треде, далее запускаем асинктаск(и) внутри которых создаем хэндлер с сообщением что надо обновить такой-то виджет, далее через колбэк хэндлера получаем сообщение и спокойно обновляем виджет
2. Можно тупо через например `textView.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           textView.setText(yourText);
       }}` - по сути сообщаем виджету, что как только управление попадет в юай тред его ждет работенка по обновлению.

Comment: если криво написать, то конечно не будет работать. 

> Модифицировать виджет можно только в том потоке, в котором он был создан

не нужно шифровать. виджеты в андроиде можно создавать только в gui треде. в нем и обновлять.